# Wrapfig induces an empty box on the next page

Tags: positioning, wrapfigure

I am writing a document, and have been using the wrapfig environment without problems, however, for one of my figures I encounter the following problem. The figure is placed neatly and in the right place, but on the next page of my document an extra box is created that fits the figure but is empty. I do not know why it does this. If it helps, here is the code I use:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{FigName}
\caption{\textbf{Captiontext}\textit{Captiontext}}
\label{figLabel}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Is this a known problem, or does anyone know how to get rid of this extra box?

Comment: I may have been to quick with my question. Positioning the code just after the start of the section as opposed to just before seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: If your question doesn't have an answer, you can still delete it, to keep the site clean.

Comment: Also it seems to be a known problem, loot at the `wrapfig` manual (end of page 2 begin of page 3).  You can look at the manual using `texdoc wrapfig`.